# Оформление сноски

Tags: сноски

Как правильно оформить текст сноски?
...СПб., 1869. С. 16 прим. 2.
...СПб., 1869. С. 16, прим. 2.
...СПб., 1869. С. 16. Прим. 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2. ...СПб.:название издательства (напр.Просвещение), 1869.- С. 16.

А что такое " **прим.2**" ? **Сноска № 2**? Тогда цифру 2 ставят **перед выходными данными**  в самом низу страницы, но вверху строки:

http://polusspb.ru/article/a-44.html

https://studfiles.net/preview/2462835/page:3/

Comment: Я думаю, что "прим. 2" это примечание 2 на с. 16. Вопрос в том, писать ли "прим. 2" через зпт после страницы или как новое предложение.

Comment: Это не входит в выходные данные источника и в сносках не указывается, а указывается в тексте работы, если это надо: в параграфе таком-то (прим.2) говорится: "..." Но если Вам это так необходимо и вопрос только в пунктуации, то лучше указать в скобках или уж через запятую после страницы, но тогда и параграф надо указывать, иначе примечание к чему? Но обычно в сносках это не указывается, только страница.